# Cleaning up a Google App Script for updating Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a script that we use to update dropdown options on more than one Google Form. I am NOT a developer or anything even close but thanks to years of trial and error I can usually get what I want out of a script.

Below is the current script that we use, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way of writing this script that does not involve that giant chunks of repeated code. I fear if we continue to add more files to this to update it will take a lot more resources and time to run.

Thanks for any advice!

PS this is a working script and I have changed the Form_ID's to a generic name.

````
  const GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME = "FormData";
  const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = "Google Form ID";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const [header, ...data] = ss
    .getSheetByName(GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME)
    .getDataRange()
    .getDisplayValues();

  const choices = {};
  header.forEach((title, i) => {
    choices[title] = data.map((d) => d[i]).filter((e) => e);
  });

  FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID)
    .getItems()
    .map((item) => ({
      item,
      values: choices[item.getTitle()],
    }))
    .filter(({ values }) => values)
    .forEach(({ item, values }) => {
      switch (item.getType()) {
        case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
          item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
          item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        default:
        // ignore item
      }
    });
  ss.toast("Google Form Updated !!");
};

{
  const GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME = "FormData";
  const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = "Google Form ID2";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const [header, ...data] = ss
    .getSheetByName(GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME)
    .getDataRange()
    .getDisplayValues();

  const choices = {};
  header.forEach((title, i) => {
    choices[title] = data.map((d) => d[i]).filter((e) => e);
  });

  FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID)
    .getItems()
    .map((item) => ({
      item,
      values: choices[item.getTitle()],
    }))
    .filter(({ values }) => values)
    .forEach(({ item, values }) => {
      switch (item.getType()) {
        case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
          item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
          item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        default:
        // ignore item
      }
    });
  ss.toast("Google Form Updated !!");
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME = "FormData";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ['id1', 'id2'].forEach(GOOGLE_FORM_ID => {
    const [header, ...data] = ss
      .getSheetByName(GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME)
      .getDataRange()
      .getDisplayValues();
    const choices = {};
    header.forEach((title, i) => {
      choices[title] = data.map((d) => d[i]).filter((e) => e);
    });

    FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID)
      .getItems()
      .map((item) => ({
        item,
        values: choices[item.getTitle()],
      }))
      .filter(({ values }) => values)
      .forEach(({ item, values }) => {
        switch (item.getType()) {
          case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
            item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(values);
            break;
          case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
            item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
            break;
          case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
            item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(values);
            break;
          default:
          // ignore item
        }
      });
  });
  ss.toast("Google Forms Updated !!");
}
```